# How to run Flask function that triggers on user's action and add content to the page?

Tags: python, flask

The idea is that user push the button and Flask should add some content on the page. 
In my case python and Flask **is not** an aleatory choice, because Python make a lot of backdoor work (that for example js can't). 
And perfectly it should be just one page without redirection on another page. 
So my question is:

1. How to get the moment when user push the button and run the function I want
2. How to make this function add some generated content on the page without reloading.

Comment: this has nothing to do with flask... the functionality you want is javascript ... :/

Comment: Ok, but as I said python chosen because I use python packages and it can't be replaced by js.

Comment: they arent replacements for eachother ... they work differently, flask manages your backend... there is no way for flask to change your content without reloading the page... you are missing some key understanding of web technology stack knowledge that is required to solve your problem

Comment: okay, I will try to figure out how to do it with js. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As one of the commenters said, you are missing some key concepts in the web development stack you are working with. Lemme try to explain.

- Flask is a backend framework/server. It receives requests from your browser and generates and sends a response. Your browser can make a request and load the response as a new page.
- JavaScript runs in the browser (or to use a more generic term frontend). It can make changes to the way the current page looks and behaves without reloading. It can make requests to the backend, process the results it receives and act on them.

There are two basic ways browser makes a request to the backend. When you load a page. And when your Javascript code makes an XHR request.

There are three basic ways your frontend does things in response to user actions.

- Run some javascript and do something without making any requests. For example, highlight a button user is hovering his mouse over, autocomplete what user is typing from some pre-defined list, switch UI tabs, hide/show elements etc.
- Make a request to the backend and load the results as a new page. For example, follow a link to a new page on the site, submit a form, reload the page etc. This is how most web applications used to work 10-15 years ago.
- Run some javascript and use it to make a request to the backend in the background. Use javascript to process the results and update the page dynamically without reloading. This is how most web applications work now.

Basically, there are two ways to do what you want, the old way, where you have your Flask app generate the whole page with your new content and send it to the browser. This will make the browser reload the page. And the new way, where your Flask app just provides the data you want to change and the javascript in teh browser makes an XHR request in the background and uses the data to update the page. This can happen without a reload and this is the way most modern web apps work.

I hope this clears things up for you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

#### app.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/add_item")
def add_item():
    #in reality you are doing something else i imagine
    return "<li>%s</li>"%(request.args.get('name'))

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html',items=["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

#### templates/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="items_holder">
{% for item in items %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<button id="do_something">Do Something</button>
</body>
<script src="/static/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

#### static/app.js

```
$(function(){
    $("#do_something").click(function(){
        var item_name = prompt("enter item name")
        $.get("/add_item?name="+item_name,function(result_data){
            $('#items_holder').append(result_data)
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you! First answer on point. But is it necessary to use jqvery?